# What is the difference between dpkg and aptitude/apt-get?

Tags: apt, dpkg, aptitude

When installing a software via `dpkg -i packageA.deb`, will the dependencies required by `packageA` be downloaded and installed automatically? How is this different from using `apt-get` or `aptitude`?

Comment: Related (especially regarding dependencies): https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/250300

Answer (score 212, accepted):

No, **`dpkg`** only installs a package, so doing `dpkg -i packageName.deb` will only install this Deb package, and will notify you of any dependencies that need to be installed, but it will ***not*** install them, and it will ***not*** configure the `packageName.deb` because well...the dependencies are not there.

**`apt-get`** is a [**Package Management System**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) that handles the installation of Deb packages on [Debian-based Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Debian-based). A Package Management System is a set of tools that will help you install, remove, and change packages easily. So `apt-get` is like a clever `dpkg`.

I like to think of the timeline this way (the following is just me speaking from experience. It is meant to only give you an idea of this whole thing):

- They came up with a way to "store" the files of an application in a "package" so that it can be easily installed. So, the Deb package ([`.deb` extension file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format))) was born.

  > A `.deb` file contains the files needed by an application to run, as well as *(I like to call it)* "meta-data" that holds other information, such as the names of the dependencies the application needs. If you want to see the contents of a `.deb` file, you can use the command `dpkg -c packageName.deb`, and if you want to see this "meta-data" information, use the command `dpkg -I pacakgeName.deb` (and if you want to only see the dependencies, do `dpkg -I packageName.deb | grep Depends`).
- They needed a tool to install these `.deb` files, so they came up with the `dpkg` tool. This tool, however, will just install the `.deb` file, but will not install its dependencies because it doesn't have those files and it does not have access to "repositories" to go pull the dependencies from.
- Then, they came up with `apt-get`, which automates the problems in the previous point. Underneath the hood, `apt-get` is basically `dpkg` (I like to think of it as `apt-get` being a front-end for `dpkg`), but a clever one that will look for the dependencies and install them. It even looks at the currently installed dependencies and determines ones that are not being used by any other packages, and will inform you that you can remove them.

**`aptitude`** then came along. It uses the [libraries `apt-get` uses](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-frontends.html) and actually has an interactive UI (user interface). If you want to see this UI, simply type `aptitude` in the terminal. *That's* `aptitude`. It leverages the libraries to provide more options and perks than `apt-get`. For example, `aptitude` will automatically remove eligible packages, while `apt-get` needs a separate command to do so. But, in the end, doing `sudo aptitude install packageName.deb` should *at least* be the same as `sudo apt-get install packageName.deb`. There might be subtle differences here and there that I do not know about, but they will both look for the dependencies and do all that stuff. You can read [the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/767/38128) for more information on the differences between `aptitude` and `apt-get`.

Also, `aptitude` does not have Super Cow Powers.

> EDIT: Apparently, it does. `aptitude -v[v[v[v[v]]]] moo`.

`aptitude` might not be installed by default. To install it, do `sudo apt-get install aptitude` or click this: [aptitude [image: Install aptitude]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptitude).

---

## Extra

> The following information doesn't really directly answer "*What is the difference between dpkg and aptitude/apt-get?*" but it contributes to the big picture.

---

<sub>From [Carlos Campderrós](https://askubuntu.com/users/43549/carlos-campderros)' [comment below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get/309121#comment389851_309121):</sub>

**`gdebi`** is another tool that is kind of a mixture between `apt-get` and `aptitude`. When you use it to install a `.deb` package (`gdebi packageName.deb`), it will identify the missing dependencies, install them using `apt-get`, and then finally install and configure the package using `dpkg`. It even has a [simple and neat GUI that gives you information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68mxg.png) about the `.deb` package, the files included in the package, and what dependencies need to be installed. To see this GUI, you would do `gdebi-gtk packageName.deb`. You can give `gdebi` a try by installing it with `sudo apt-get install gdebi` or click this: [gdebi [image: Install gdebi]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gdebi).

---

I don't want to confuse anyone, but just to give you another part of the picture, there is another popular Linux package format called RPM, and its files have the `.rpm` extension. This package format is used on [**RPM-based** Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#RPM-based) (such as Red Hat, CentOS, and Fedora). They use the command `rpm` to install a package, and `yum` is the front-end for it, it's the clever one. So their `.rpm` files are our `.deb` files, their `rpm` tool is our `dpkg` tool, and their `yum` is our `apt-get`.

<sub>From [Paddy Landau](https://askubuntu.com/users/2088/paddy-landau)'s [comment below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get#comment394609_309121):</sub>

**`alien`** is a tool that converts between `.rpm` and `.deb` packages. So if you ever fall into the situation where you have an `.rpm` package, and you want to install in on your Ubuntu (or any other Debian-based distro), you can use the command `alien rpm_packageName.rpm` to convert it to `.deb`, and then install it using `dpkg`. You can do the reverse (convert `.deb` to `.rpm`) using `alien -r packageName.deb`.

Comment: Also, you can use `gdebi` (`apt-get install gdebi-core`) that mixes `apt-get`/`aptitude` with `dpkg`. You call it with `gdebi some_package.deb` and it will analyze its dependencies, call `apt-get` to install the missing ones and when all dependencies are fulfilled, then call `dpkg` to finally install your package.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós, I've added `gdebi` in my answer.

Comment: @Alaa Under **Extra**, you can also mention that `alien` converts packages between `.rpm` and `.deb`. This is useful for packages available for RPM but not for DEB (or vice-versa). For example, `alien packagename.rpm` to make it usable for Ubuntu.

Comment: Just a minor correction for you; aptitude does have Super Cow Powers: aptitude -v[v[v[v[v]]]] moo

Comment: @AlaaAli `aptitude` is not a frontend for `apt-get`. [Both programs are frontends for the `libapt-pkg` library.](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-frontends.html)

Comment: @AlaaAli hey I need to ask you some questions about package installation. please give me some kind of contact source

Comment: @edwardtorvalds AskUbuntu is a question and answer site. Search for your answer here on the site from the thousands of old questions, and if you don't find it, ask your own question, more experienced people than me will hopefully also answer.

Comment: @AlaaAli i did ali. but no one is answering thats why i asked you to help me personally. :( :( its just a favour

Answer (score 7):

## apt-get

Package management via `apt-get` runs hand-in-hand with the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

`apt-get install <package_name>`
installs a new package onto your computer.

`apt-get build-dep <package_name>`
This command searches the repositories and installs the build dependencies for . If the package is not in the repositories it will return an error.

`apt-get install <package1_name> <package2_name> <package3_name>`
apt-get allows multiple package installation. separate the packages with a space.

`auto-apt run <command_string>`
When invoked, the auto-apt command automatically installs packages upon missing file access. If a program tries to access a file known to belong in an uninstalled package, auto-apt will install that package using `apt-get`. This feature requires apt and sudo to work.

[Visit the apt-get instruction page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto?action=show&redirect=AptGetHowTo)

## aptitude

`aptitude` provides the functionality of `dselect` and `apt-get` as well as many additional features not found in either program.

`aptitude` has a shell of its own which is keyboard or mouse activated and runs in a terminal window

`aptitude build-dep <package>`   - Install the build-dependencies of packages - which means the packages needed to compile (or *build*) its source package. For example, many packages need `debhelper` or `autotools` to be built, but don't need them to run.

[Visit the aptitude instruction page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptitudeSurvivalGuide)

## dpkg

is  a  tool to install, build, remove and manage Debian packages. [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/dpkg.1.html)

`dpkg -i <package.deb>` installs a Debian package onto your computer.  It does not install any dependencies as far as I can find out from the help files.

For details type `dpkg --help` into a terminal window.

## Guides

a guide to file management can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement)

Answer (score 3):

Although there are great answers to this question I want to say something more detailed.

- `dpkg` (or `rpm` in Fedora family) is a *Low-level* tool which
  installs and removes package files, it doesn't install the
  dependencies or search it from repositories.
- `apt`, `apt-get` and `aptitude` (or `yum` and `dnf` in Fedora family) are *High-level* - or as it mentioned in [first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/309121/1075611) a
  *front-end* of `dpkg`! - tools that perform metadata searching and dependency
  resolution.

I like to explain their differences in **package management** tasks in Linux:

1. For install, uninstall or updating a package from repositories, I use high level ones(`apt-get install`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get remove`) but for install and upgrade from a package file, I use low level ones(`dpkg -i package_file`, ).
2. For search in repositories, I use high level tool (`apt-cache search search_str` )
3. For checking the installed packages and files I use low level ones
   (`dpkg -l` or `-s` or `-S` for more info check the manual `man dpkg | less` )
4. For package metadata I use high level ones, for example `apt-cache show dpkg`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important thing and also a difference is to note is that you should use `apt-get` tool to install packages. (`apt` or `aptitude` is fine as well).

This is because `dpkg` is meant to install packages without installing dependent packages.
Because of that just installing a package with `dpkg`, may lead to a later problem where dependency resolution may end up with a broken system.

You should use the command line `apt-get` or `apt` (since 14.04) tool to install packages. These tools are using `dpkg` for you and at the same time do have the dependency resolution mechanism inside.