# Tools for Package Managing

Tags: apt, package-management

I've had numerous problems in the past where `apt-get` fails to do something and gives a confusing reason why which doesn't help me solve the problem, but `aptitude` guesses some alternative action that fixes things.

Should I always use `aptitude` to avoid these problems in the first place? I'm just trying to understand whether there are drawbacks to the tool or I'm just missing some critical knowledge about using `apt-get` that makes me prone to errors.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? It'd also be helpful to say what kind of commands and errors you've used, e.g. do you always run `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install new packages or upgrade?

Comment: It's not a problem that's tied to any version; I've had issues on both 12.04 and 14.04. Also, `update` doesn't have anything to do with it.


I'm asking about situations you can get into, especially when trying to install a package with a dependency that you have the incorrect version of, where `apt-get` doesn't know how to make changes and yet `aptitude` can just solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get) more detailed information about differences between package managers.

As for `apt-get` you reffered to new dependencies of a package that gets hold or etc. `apt-get` has a command (function) which is not always used in common for example to update and upgrade packages:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs
```

the command with `--with-new-pkgs` is very useful sometimes and it means:

```
   Allow installing new packages when used in conjunction with
   upgrade. This is useful if the update of a installed package
   requires new dependencies to be installed. Instead of holding the
   package back upgrade will upgrade the package and install the new
   dependencies. Note that upgrade with this option will never remove
   packages, only allow adding new ones.
```

Comment: Good one! **:-)** Upvoted!  I'm going to adapt my answer to include yours...  (alternatively, you can do the same and then I'll delete mine.  Let me know your preference)

Answer (score 0):

Always use `sudo apt-get upgrade` until you run into problems.

Then use:

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

If that still poses problems use:

2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs`

And only then use:

3. `aptitude` *and cycle through the proposed solutions* and take the best one for you!

Otherwise, one of these days you're going to back yourself into a corner you won't get out of any more …

Also, [start making system back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/a/581953/344926) if you're not making those yet and keep at least 2 system back-ups.

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**