# ImportError: No module named dbus

Tags: python, software-center, dbus

I was trying to update my Python and messed up my whole system.

I am currently now able to start my Software Centre. I tried Googling multiple fixes but nothing helped. My Software Centre can't start.

When I try starting it up, this error shows:

```
astephen@localhost:/usr/bin$ ./software-centerGtk-Message: Failed to load module "gtk-vector-screenshot"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./software-center", line 36, in <module>
from softwarecenter.utils import (
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
import dbus
ImportError: No module named dbus
```

I tried reinstalling `dbus` using:

```
apt-get install --reinstall dbus
```

But it did not help.

```
astephen@localhost:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbusReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not      upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/231 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 676272 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dbus_1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dbus (1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3) over (1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dbus (1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3) ...
```

Comment: I am on mobile currently, but I am pretty sure it is not dbus you need to (re) install, but something like python-dbus or python3-dbus (python bindings) If you use synaptic, you can easily search for t he right one.

Comment: i tried to run     
    sudo -h pip install dbus

however it returned :  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dbus

Any ideas ? :(

Comment: Did you try what @user72216 said?

Answer (score 4):

A quick search reveals that the name of the Debian package for the Python DBUS module is called `python-dbus` (or `python3-dbus`). Why it isn't available despite being an explicit dependency of the `software-center` package is beyond me. You should re-install the two packages in case they were corrupted:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center python-dbus
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, it's been two years since that question was asked, but this didn't stop me to waste my time on the same problem.

```
pip3 install dbus-python
```

made me just run into some problems like:

```
... 
checking python extra linking flags... -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
  checking consistency of all components of python development environment... no
  configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-407jqhld/dbus-python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7':
  configure: error:
    Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
    installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
    via the LIBS environment variable.
    Example: ./configure LIBS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
    ============================================================================
     ERROR!
     You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
     for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
    ============================================================================

  See `config.log' for more details
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-407jqhld/dbus-python/setup.py", line 111, in <module>
      tests_require=['tap.py'],
    File "/home/schwaigeradm/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/schwaigeradm/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-407jqhld/dbus-python/setup.py", line 64, in run
      cwd=builddir)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-build-407jqhld/dbus-python/configure', '--disable-maintainer-mode', 'PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3', '--prefix=/tmp/pip-build-407jqhld/dbus-python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/prefix']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dbus-python
  Running setup.py clean for dbus-python
Failed to build dbus-python
```

Installing or re-installing of any of my current software didn't help. But I realized it's a python3.7 issue:

As in python2.7 it was possible to add import dbus, but in pyhon3.7 it failed with the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

---

**The solution is rather easy:**

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev
pip3 install dbus-python
```

Comment: Still gives the same error you mentioned!

Answer (score 3):

You must install `dbus-python` package using `pip` or `pip3`:

```
pip3 install dbus-python
```

or

```
pip install dbus-python
```

You may need `sudo` before the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

> Adrian O'neil Stephen
>   :
>
> i tried to run sudo -h pip install dbus however it returned : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for dbus Any ideas ? :( –

Further information on what you did would be helpful, however, my hunches:

## Consider a python3 upgrade issue

When upgrading to python3, the modules sometimes change names / the import procedure changes; did you remove your old python environment manually or installed something from git?

## Try [aptitude](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get)

Install aptitude, it recommends ways to solve dependencies. Be careful, however, always check what it wants to do, which other stuff may be affected by this change, and **write down what you do, and what aptitude does** *so you always can undo possible missteps*.

## Reinstall your System

Sometimes it's just best to nuke everything (in a convoluted OS error issue, after backing up everything, using the export function of the apps apps you want to backup, preferrably. That makes things way easier).

Answer (score 0):

If your python3 module cannot find the right version of packages, a possible hack is to create symlinks to old versions.
In case of dbus, you can do the following. (Say you just upgrade python3.5 to python3.6)

`$ cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
$ ln -s _dbus_glib_bindings.cpython-{35m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

If you get further errors, try to link all packages.

```
a=$(find /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -name '*35m*so')
b=$(echo $a | tr 35m 36m)
IFS=' ' read -r -a a <<< $a
IFS=' ' read -r -a b <<< $b

for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]};++i)); do
    ln -s "${a[i]}" "${b[i]}"
done
```