# Ubuntu Cleaner for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not working Only Icon Appear

Tags: 16.04, dbus

I have recently installed **Ubuntu cleaner** following http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/free-space-ubuntu-cleaner-janitor-app.

The problem I am facing now is that the icon appears, but each time I click on it, nothing happens. Only the mouse cursor is indicating that it's loading the program, but nothing else happens.

---

I have tried `ubuntu-cleaner` in terminal and this is the outcome:

```
$ ubuntu-cleaner 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-cleaner", line 7, in <module> 
    import dbus ImportError: No module named dbus
```

so what does that mean?

Comment: Close it then start it from the terminal as `ubuntu-cleaner` then edit your question and include any errors you get in the terminal window here.

Comment: Also since it's just a component of the good old Ubuntu Tweak, you might also like to try an updated version of Ubuntu Tweak (including one for xenial) together with a number of other very useful tools from here: https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-tweak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named dbus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801195/importerror-no-module-named-dbus)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Converting the OP's comments to an answer:</sup>

A solution was posted [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346664).

Installing the package `python-dbus` should fix the issue.