# Can't install libxi-dev and libxmu-dev on Ubuntu 16.04 because of unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I need libxmu-dev and libxi-dev to be able to run OpengGl with CMake, but I can't seem to be able to install them.

When I run `sudo apt install libxmu-dev libxi-dev` the following happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxi-dev : Depends: libxi6 (= 2:1.7.5-1) but 2:1.7.6-1 is to be installed
 libxmu-dev : Depends: libxmu6 (= 2:1.1.2-1ubuntu1) but 2:1.1.2-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to do : `sudo apt update`  before the install attempt.

Comment: I didn't forget. I updated and tried to install and I still have the same unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install them using `aptitude`. It will suggest you different solutions to resolve the dependencies. Accept the one that downgrades the packages on which `libxi-dev` and `libxmu-dev` depend.

First, install `aptitude`:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Then, install your packages using `aptitude`:

```
sudo aptitude install libxi-dev libxmu-dev
```

The first solution will be:

```
     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libxi-dev [Not Installed]
2)     libxmu-dev [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Do **not** accept this solution. This will simply not install your packages. Enter **`n`**.

The next solution will be:

```
     Downgrade the following packages:
1)     libxi6 [2:1.7.6-1 (now) -> 2:1.7.5-1 (xenial)]
2)     libxmu6 [2:1.1.2-2 (now) -> 2:1.1.2-1ubuntu1 (xenial)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Enter `y` to accept this solution. This will downgrade `libxi6` and `libxmu6`, and then install `libxi-dev` and `libxmu-dev`.

Comment: Does this mean that Aptitude can resolve conflicts and Apt does not? In a interactive way.

Comment: @ricardo-rodrigues you can read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/309121/602670) for more info.