# Download mongodb compass and Install Using the Terminal

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, mongodb

I tried to follow the commands based on this link [Download and Install Compass — MongoDB Compass stable](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/)

I have downloaded the package mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb and tried installing using

```
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb;
```

But I'm getting dependency problems:

```
(Reading database ... 195489 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-compass (1.15.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-compass:
 mongodb-compass depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-compass (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-compass
```

How do I fix installation error in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error. However, when I installed it using Software Center it was successfully installed. 
To install it using Software Center, double click on the .deb package and Click install.

Comment: Indeed.. installing the missing package did not worked via shell.. it says yet another dependency wasn't met and one should execute fix or something command.. good one thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo apt install -f` to fix dependency problems.

Also its better to install it using APT like

```
sudo apt install ./filename
```

Differences between APT and DPKG are described here: [What is the difference between dpkg and aptitude/apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/)

Comment: What's difference when you use `apt install ./filename` instead of `dpkg -i filename`?

Comment: @ldias answered in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get)

Comment: @ldias APT would try to fetch and resolve dependencies on it's own from official repositories or the configured 3rd party PPA/repositories while on the other hand, `dpkg` won't resolve that on its own. APT is the front-end for dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Run
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

then

```
`sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb;`
```

This will fix the problem.